# What would be the opposite of "Divine Saint King"?

Tags: word-choice

In a fanfiction that I am writing, a character has the title of *Divine Saint Kaiser* (Kaiser being translated to King). At one point she is kidnapped and the ones responsible who know of her ancestry plan on killing her as they call her the *"Demon Child of the **_ _** Tyrant"*, believing that if she's alive it'll spark a repeat of a civil war called the Saint King Unification War.

The idea is that they are calling her the opposite to Divine Saint King, I've chosen Tyrant to replace King because Divine Saint King sounds benevolent and kind (so the opposite to that would be an iron fist cruel tyrant).

I would like to know what I could use as the opposite of *Divine* and *Saint*, preferably avoiding *Demon* as I don't want the title to repeat it when it's used in *Demon Child*.

EDIT: The material my fiction is based from is *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha*, for those who don't know the civilization which uses [Saint Kaiser](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Saint_King) is Belka whose language is similar to German, however there are inconsistencies as Kaiser = Emperor not King. However, it's probably not mistranslated as there is a character whose ancestor was an [Emperor](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Victoria_Dahlgr%C3%BCn).

Also, while in Nanoha, the Saint King isn't referred to as the *Divine Saint King*. I chose to add Divine because a character has 2 titles, [*Dark Ruler*](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Claus_Ingvalt) (see last sentence) and [*Flame King*](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Victoria_Dahlgr%C3%BCn) (see 2nd paragraph, last sentence) and I've chosen to combine the 2 titles to be *Dark Flame King*, I feel if i give one Belkan Ruler a 3 worded title I should do the same with all the rest, I chose Divine to go with Saint as Divine can also be seen as holy and I remember reading somewhere that Kings were at one time thought to have been chosen by God.

Comment: Are you writing this in English, or writing it in, say, German and then translating it into English? Because *Divine* (=god-like) doesn't usually go with *Saint*, which rather colours the rest of the question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach is right. Beyond that, consider **googling for antonyms** of*devine* (or *saint*) and *king* (or whatever). If you are **making up a name** by composing such pieces then you don't really need to start by asking for help here, IMHO.  Instead, come up with a name after searching a bit, and then ask here whether what you came up with makes sense.

Comment: I've edited my question (because of text limit in comments), please let me know if that doesn't clear things up

Comment: @Drew to be honest i didn't know of the word antonym and experience with searching google was that human like questions like "opposite meaning words to divine/saint" normally comes up with weird results, ofcause now i know of the word antonym i might have a better chance with google now

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to find an antonym for Divine or Saint.  If Divine, perhaps "Profane"?  If Saint, I think "Demon Prince" is probably as good as you'll get.   There are several descriptions of demonic hierarchies, but they don't seem to have poetic names like Seraphim, et al.  "Demon Prince of the Profane Tyrant"?

Comment: There is no exact antonym to saint, perhaps you can use heretic or apostate (or wrathful or ruthless , if its on the context of disposition). Maybe something like *Infernal Ruthless Tyrant* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal choice is "[Subterranean](https://www.wordnik.com/words/subterranean) [Unrighteous](https://www.wordnik.com/words/unrighteous) Tyrant".

You can also use the permutations for the antonyms of ["divine"](http://thesaurus.com/browse/divine) and ["saintly"](http://thesaurus.com/browse/saintly).